# Why do I get a segfault when writing to a file using mmap?

Tags: c, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapped-io

I recently learned from a YouTube video that we can read from or write to files by mapping them into memory. The video showed how read some contents from a text file and print them out and also change some of characters of the text file. I tried to write some contents to a file using this technique but whenever I build and run my code, I face segmentation fault (core dumped) error and I don't know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#define SIZE 5 * sizeof(float)

int main()
{
    float *info = (float*) malloc (SIZE);
    if(info == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        *(info + counter) = counter + 1;

    FILE *file = fopen("information.dat", "w");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    float *memory = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(file), 0);

    for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
    {
        *(memory + counter) = *(info + counter);
        printf("%5.2f has been saved in the file.\n", *(info + counter));
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(info);
}
```

My operating system is ubuntu 18.04 and I use GCC 7.3.0 compiler.

Comment: `mmap()` cannot be used to increase the size of the file.

Comment: You need to call `ftruncate()` to set the size of the file before mapping it.

Comment: You should check the return value of `mmap`. It may return `MAP_FAILED` to indicate an error. In this case, `memory` dereferenced. Use a debugger to see at which point in your program you get the segmentation fault.

Comment: [`MAP_PRIVATE` will mean all writes to the file never get saved to disk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html): "If `MAP_PRIVATE` is specified, modifications to the mapped data by the calling process shall be visible only to the calling process and shall not change the underlying object."